# java complex if statement causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I made a recursive method to find the least number of rallies that could be played before one or another team wins with given points team should score to win - k,  current points of two teams - x and y.

So it looked like

```
public static int scores(int k, int x, int y, int rally) {
    if (x==k || y==k)
        return rally;
    else {
        rally++;
        return Math.min(scores(k, x + 1, y, rally), scores(k, x,y+1,rally));
    }
}
```

When I called this method with custom values in main method

```
scores(5,0,0,0)
```

It worked fine. But when I changed IF statement to check that the winner has at least two-point margin

```
if ((x==k || y==k) && Math.abs(x-y)>=2)
```

The program showed java.lang.StackOverflowError

I am extremely bad at this, please help me

Comment: You added one additional condition to the exit from recursion. As a result the method don't exit and invokes scores() until the exception

Comment: Take note that you never increase k value, that means that if x/y == k and difference isn't 2 points, it will pass on and x/y will never equal k again.

Comment: I don't see the difference between `if ((x==k || y==k) && (Math.abs(x-y))>=2)` and `if ((x==k || y==k) && Math.abs(x-y)>=2)`. (Other than the unnecessary brackets being removed).

Comment: [I downvoted because there was no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), e.g. printing the values of `k`, `x`, `y`, and `rally` inside the method.

Comment: Isn't the solution just trivially `Math.max(2, k)`? (The minimum number of rallies is where X always beats Y, or vice versa). No recursion needed.

Comment: @AndyTurner oh right, I messed up and pasted wrong code block

Comment: @ОльгаКужикова after your edit, the answer is simply `k`.

Answer (score 2):

Take note that you never increase k value, that means that if x/y == k and difference isn't 2 points, it will pass on and x/y will never equal k again.

I will imagine that something like this, should work

```
public static int scores(int k, int x, int y, int rally) {
    if ((x>=k || y>=k) && (Math.abs(x-y))>=2)
        return rally;
    else {
        rally++;
        return Math.min(scores(k, x + 1, y, rally), scores(k, x,y+1,rally));
    }
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, there is another issue with this code, that causes SO when opposite players get one point each all the time.

---

You can fix the stack overflow error that occurs when X and y alternate in "winning" by keeping track of the minimum found so far:

```
public static int scores(int k, int x, int y, int rally) {
  return scores(k, x, y, rally, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

public static int scores(int k, int x, int y, int rally, int minSoFar) {
    if (rally >= minSoFar || ((x>=k || y>=k) && (Math.abs(x-y))>=2))
        return rally;
    else {
        rally++;
        minSoFar = Math.min(minSoFar, scores(k, x+1, y, rally));
        minSoFar = Math.min(minSoFar, scores(k, x, y+1, rally));
        return minSoFar;
    }
}
```

But it should be noted that the minimum path will always be the one where X always wins (or Y always wins). So:

```
return Math.max(2, k);
```

Is a much easier way to express the result.

Comment: This code will generate the same stack overflow exception, x or y being larger than k is irrelevant here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson are you thinking of the [Isner-esque situation](https://www.teamusa.org/News/2018/July/13/After-Second-Longest-Grand-Slam-Match-Ever-John-Isner-Falls-Just-Short-Of-Wimbledon-Final) of the increment x, increment y, increment x, increment y (etc) path?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I like how you point it out as irrelevant - when its one of problems with this code that causes SO. I will admit to my answer being incomplete (Didn't test it), but its not irrelevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner yea, thats the second part (that I missed) - we end up always going back to equal scores.

Comment: Yes you're right. The second part of my comment was _irrelevant_

Comment: @Worthless I've tacked on a lot to your answer, because I couldn't post my own. Hope that's ok.